Spring Boot using a bean from a config class that is not specified in the @Import annotation
I am trying to implement two tests for a Spring Batch Job, each test needing one bean in particular to have different properties when the Spring Context loads it in.
One test class is the following:
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.app"})
@Import(JobTestConfig.class)
public class JobTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void testJob() throws Exception {
        jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(new JobParameters());
        // ...
    }
}

And the config for the test class is
public class JobTestConfig {

    DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder embeddedDatabaseBuilder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return embeddedDatabaseBuilder
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                .setName("dataSource;mode=Oracle")
                .addScript("db/cleanup.sql")
                .addScript("db/DDL.sql")
                .addScript("db/DML.sql")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = new DataSourceBuilder();
        dataSourceBuilder.setAvailableDataSources(Map.of("data", dataSource()));
        return dataSourceBuilder;
    }

    @Bean
    SqlStatements sqlStatements() {
        SqlStatements sqlStatements = new SqlStatements();
        sqlStatements.setSomeQuery("TheQuery")
        return sqlStatements;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() {
        return new JobLauncherTestUtils();
    }
}

I have a JobTestTwo and a JobTestConfigTwo with only one difference to the above classes: the ´sqlStatements.setSomeQuery()´ sets a different query, no other changes.
Running the tests in JobTest yields the expected results, but when running JobTestTwo, despite it being annotated with @Import(JobTestTwoConfig.class), it uses the SqlStatements bean declared in JobTestConfig, failing the tests.
I have tried with implementing both JobTestConfig as inner classes, with using @ContextConfiguration over @Import, and with using @Profile + @ActiveProfile (not all at the same time), but JobTestTwo keeps using SqlStatements from JobTestConfig, and not the one from JobTestTwoConfig.
JUnit version is 4.12, Spring Batch version is 4.2.1, Spring Boot version is 2.2.6.
Thank you very much for any help!
EDIT: Found the solution in my case:
I've left the common beans between the two tests in one class:
@TestConfiguration
public class JobTestConfig {

    @Bean
    JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() {
        return new JobLauncherTestUtils();
    }

    // use this bean instead of the one defined outside tests
    @Bean
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = new DataSourceBuilder();
        dataSourceBuilder.setAvailableDataSources(Map.of("data", dataSource()));
        return dataSourceBuilder;
    }

    // use this bean instead of the one defined outside tests
    DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder embeddedDatabaseBuilder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return embeddedDatabaseBuilder
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                .setName("dataSource;mode=Oracle")
                .addScript("db/cleanup.sql")
                .addScript("db/DDL.sql")
                .addScript("db/DML.sql")
                .build();
    }
}


And in each JobTest class I have an inner class with the particular bean that needs diferent properties depending on the test:
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.app"})
@Import(JobTest.ContextConfiguration.class)
public class JobTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void testJob() throws Exception {
        jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(new JobParameters());
        // assert...
    }

    static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        SqlStatements sqlStatements() {
            SqlStatements sqlStatements = new SqlStatements();
            sqlStatements.setSomeQuery("TheQuery");
            return sqlStatements;
        }
    }
} 


Other JobTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.app"})
@Import(JobTestTwo.ContextConfiguration.class)
public class JobTestTwo {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void testJob() throws Exception {
        jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(new JobParameters());
        // assert...
    }

    static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        SqlStatements sqlStatements() {
            SqlStatements sqlStatements = new SqlStatements();
            sqlStatements.setSomeQuery("SomeOtherQuery");
            return sqlStatements;
        }
    }
} 


The result is that when running JobTest, Spring loads into context the SqlStatements bean with "TheQuery" set, while running JobTestTwo, Spring loads into context the SqlStatements bean with "SomeOtherQuery" set.
EDIT 2: I believe @SpringBootConfiguration was the culprit.
